# Is the usage of download managers a security risk?

Tags: anonymity, plugin

Sometimes my downloads in Tor interrupt, due to bad and unreliable internet-connections, and I start thinking if it's intelligent to use a download manager like "DownThemAll!" so I am able to resume and don't have to start the whole download anew.

But will the plugin connect via the Tor-Browser/Network.

And: Is it anonymous? (Inside and outside the Network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the plugin should work via Tor network, and it will not do anything to hurt your anonymity since it is only using multiple HTTP connections like the browser do during browsing.

Comment: Is there a safe way to prove that? Meanwhile I have tried Etherape to watch the connections when it's within the Tor-Network. But how can I know when using the clearnet?

Comment: Run Firefox with Downthemall inside a virtual machine (use virtualbox or VMware or your favorite), with nothing else making internet connections inside the virtual machine, in order to isloate those connections. Next, run Wireshark and listens to the virtual network card of the virtual machine.